# guake, starting error _dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

Tags: python, dbus

when I started guake in command line:

```
➜  guake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8
```

But, My python was build in PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

```
>>> import sys
>>> if sys.maxunicode > 65535:
...     print 'UCS4 build'
... else:
...     print 'UCS2 build'

print 'UCS4 build'
```

So, I think there is something wrong with `dbus_python`

Comment: Why do you have two Python installs?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sir, how do you know i have installed 2 pythons. I did installed 2 pythons.

Comment: Because there are two different paths given in the traceback.

Comment: Well spotted. You have `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` importing `/usr/lib/python2.7`. One of these is UCS2, the other UCS4.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, my default python is system's python. And you mean there exists conflict between the 2 python?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sir, how to detect `guake` call which library path?

Comment: Do you have `PYTHONPATH` set in your environment? `env | grep PYTHON` should be helpful here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, no, I do not have `PYTHONPATH` set in my env.

Comment: Run `which guake` , I suspect that that file is a script that runs `python -m guake`, but either sets `PYTHONPATH` or runs the wrong python binary or both.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are right sir, guake is in `/usr/bin/` and the `guake` is a script and it runs `python -m guake` and I changed  the python to my defualt  python , it works fine now! Sir, please answer my question below and I will accept your answer!